# javascript interface in not working in below 5.0

Tags: javascript, android

1. I have used below code to avoid white space when my webview expands
   it is working well in 5.0

I have added suppresslint @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface" }) to avoid error

But still white space remains in Android 4.2,4.3 devices

can someone suggest me to solve this issue.

```
web_content_url.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                    pbar2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    view.loadUrl(s[1]);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
                    pbar2.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                    pbar2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }

            });
            web_content_url.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
```